# Volume of trig function around y-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this question and it's the first kind of question I'm doing involving finding volume so I just would like some help solving this question:

Find the volume created by revolving the curve $ \ y=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ from $ x= \frac {\pi}{3}$ to $x = \pi $. about the y-axis

Comment: Please check over my edits.

Comment: The "around $y$-axis" suggests a volume of revolution, but it's not clear what "area" you would want to find for that.  How exactly is your problem phrased?

Comment: No the question states find the volume created by revolving the curve y = sin(x)/x about the y-axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the cylindrical shells formula:

The volume of the solid obtained by revolving $\{(x,y)| a \le x \le b, 0 \le y \le f(x)\}$ about the $y$-axis is:

$$V = \displaystyle\int_a^b 2\pi xf(x)\,dx$$

Applying that formula here gives $V = \displaystyle\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi} 2\pi x \dfrac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = 2\pi\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi}  \sin x\,dx$.

This gives you a simple integral to evaluate.

Comment: the answer should be 3pi right?

Comment: Yes, that is the same answer that I got.

Answer (score 2):

It will suffice to compute: $$A = \int_{\pi/3}^\pi 2\pi x f(x)~\mathrm{d}x$$
where $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$. This is exactly the shell method. Can you do it?

Comment: the answer should be 3pi right?

Comment: Looking quickly, it seems so.

Comment: Yes, [this is it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+pi%2F3+to+pi+2+pi+sin%28x%29+dx).